# npx create-react-app causes does not work after I fixed the cmd.exe location

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging

I have wrote some server side code for handling GraphQL queries for a simple calendar app that I hope to connect to a smart pill dispenser that I am building.

I want to use react to build a front-end that will send these GraphQL queries and receive back data. When I try to run `npx create-react-app client --verbose` I get the following output:

```
C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar>npx create-react-app client --verbose
```

... End of `--verbose` output.

```
npm info lifecycle resolve-from@4.0.0~postinstall: resolve-from@4.0.0
npm info lifecycle babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@6.13.0~postinstall: babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@6.13.0
npm info lifecycle babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types@0.4.24~postinstall: babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types@0.4.24
npm info lifecycle semver@5.7.1~postinstall: semver@5.7.1
npm info lifecycle core-js@2.6.11~postinstall: core-js@2.6.11

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar\client\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

which indicates that core-js is not updated. So I try to manually update core-js

with `npm install --save core-js@^3 -g` and I get the same output:

```
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.4~postuninstall: core-js@3.6.4
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 6ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 184ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 4ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 14ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.4~preinstall: core-js@3.6.4
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 2ms
npm info linkStuff core-js@3.6.4
npm timing action:build Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.4~install: core-js@3.6.4
npm timing action:install Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.4~postinstall: core-js@3.6.4

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar\node_modules\core-js>
```

And then it just kicks me out of the process and I am in some directory.

If I do `npm version core-js`, I get this.

```
C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar>npm version core-js
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\kumarm4\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'version',
npm verb cli   'core-js'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.2
npm info using node@v12.16.1
npm ERR! version No valid package.json found
npm verb stack Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar\package.json'
npm verb stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kumarm4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\version.js:118:23)
npm verb stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\kumarm4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16)
npm verb stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:256:13)
npm verb cwd C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kumarm4\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "version" "core-js"
npm verb node v12.16.1
npm verb npm  v6.14.2
npm ERR! code [
npm ERR! code   'Error: ENOENT',
npm ERR! code   'ENOENT',
npm ERR! code   index: 0,
npm ERR! code   input: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\mitesh\\javascriptcode\\calendar\\package.json'",
npm ERR! code   groups: undefined
npm ERR! code ]
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar\package.json'
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 123ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kumarm4\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-15T19_44_57_443Z-debug.log

C:\mitesh\javascriptcode\calendar>
```

Comment: I thought they are related because attempting to solve one caused the other, and now backtracking isn't fixing either of them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am not using /bin/bash?. I am using it from Windows cmd C:\ . So it obviously does not work well on Windows. I keep running into problems with using any sort of web development technology and nothing works. I showed exactly how to replicate what I have and what is not working. How is that all over the place? The error log was saying something about my Java version so I thought that it is incompatible. I am just showing my attempts to solve the problem in case someone tells me to do something I have already attempted.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know what you are talking about. I am literally using windows cmd. I search cmd in my applications, cd to my directory, and run the command. How is that in any way bash? I don't type bash, otherwise the green thing would come up... And ive uninstalled/reinstalled node many many times.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have never installed node from bash or git bash. I am going on there and typing node,  and it says node is not installed. I have deleted all things related to node from my PATH variables several times and reinstalled node, and am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah I really don't know any more. I uninstalled vscode, eclipse, wsl, cleaned up my path. Still not working... I don't know why it works for other people and not me.

Comment: Im not calling names. I am just saying that I laid out the path that caused me to arrive at a certain issue, and you are trying to help me solve issues that I arrived at and solved already. The run was showing ```/bin/bash``` because the npm script-shell was set to use bash instead of cmd. I already fixed that, but you kept saying that I was using /bin/bash. I edited my post so now it is hopefully easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for _finally_ updating your post then. Remember: the comment thread is almost entirely irrelevant for people to answer you: your post is where the information goes. If you had a different log to show all this time, I'm glad you updated your post, but please reread [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and follow it in the future. We could have cut this comment thread short ages ago instead of wasting time.

Comment: So with all that cleared up: delete your `client` dir, and rerun the create command but with the verbose flag: `npx create-react-app client --verbose`, because that will tell you exactly what create-react-app is doing.

Comment: I deleted my old comments because they were no longer relevant - what *is* relevant, though, is to run `create-react-app` with that `--verbose` flag.

Comment: I did run ```create-react-app -client --verbose```. Post was edited.

Comment: While you may have edited your post, the output you're showing is most definitely not of the `--verbose` run. Your post still shows the non-verbose console log. Read through the verbose log, see what it's saying it's (not) doing, and based on that you probably need a fairly drastic rewrite of your post because it'll have far more focussed information for you to act on (i.e. don't just update your post, _read_ the output, and _act_ on that output).

Comment: I pasted the ```--verbose``` output and It shows that it terminates core-js installation in the middle of it.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any error in that log at all. We don't see core-js "terminating" at all - if it termintated, there'd be fairly chatty NPM error report. Instead, this looks like things went just fine.

Comment: Things did not go fine, as the script terminated early, and left me in the directory it was currently working in. The main problem causes core-js to not be able to update, and because of that the script terminates.

Comment: I know, but it does mean that the information you're showing is not enough. Got a https://hastebin.com link for the full log? It also strongly suggests you should be filing an issue against create-react-app to have someone who _maintains_ that open source package take a look at what might be going wrong for you.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just using nodejs through WSL, because no one wants to help.

Comment: don't for a moment think anyone here owes you anything: if you don't update your post with up to date information, and you don't show information that allows people who have never seen this problem before, and have no way to reproduce it, let alone guess at what might be causing it, not getting help from them is not their fault. [Write a good question](/help/how-to-ask) is your best to get answers, but SO gets thousands of questions, and if your question isn't well formulated enough when you initially post it, it'll simply fall off everyone's list of visible questions.

Comment: No, I am saying, no one wants to help me on github, so I will just take the crude approach once again and use WSL. This will probably cause me even bigger problems later, but I guess there is no other way.